# Linq entityref assignment in one to many relation

Tags: database, linq, windows-phone-7, database-design, windows-phone-7.1

i have some problem with my linq database with a one to many relation. Here are classes:

```
    private EntityRef<Account> _account;

    [Association(Storage = "_account", ThisKey = "IDMovement", OtherKey = "IDAccount", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Account Account
    {
        get { return this._account.Entity; }
        set
        {
            Account previousValue = this._account.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) || (this._account.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Account");
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._account.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.Movements.Remove(this);
                }
                this._account.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.Movements.Add(this);
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Account");
            }
        }
    }
```

and on the other side:

```
private EntitySet<Movement> _movements;

    [Association(Storage = "_movements", OtherKey = "IDMovement", ThisKey = "IDAccount")]
    public EntitySet<Movement> Movements
    {
        get { return this._movements; }
        set { this._movements.Assign(value); }
    }

    private void OnMovementAdded(Movement movement)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanging("Movement");
        movement.Account = this;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Movement");
    }

    private void OnMovementRemoved(Movement movement)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanging("Movement");
        movement.Account = null;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Movement");
    }
```

my problem is that when i have to insert new movements in the database i don't know how to assign the "EntityRef _account" variable with a value that i already have in the database.

For example: i have to insert a movement for the account "general", this account is already in my database of course...how can i say to my movement that the account "general" that it has in "movement.Account" it's exactly the same included in my database?

I tried something like that but It doesn't work because it's like i have created a new account:

```
Movement movement = new Movement();
            movement.Category = (from f in context.Categories
                         where f.Name == this.Categories.ElementAt(this.ChoosenCategory).Name
                         select f).FirstOrDefault();
            movement.Account = (from f in context.Accounts
                     where f.Name == ChoosenAccount.Name
                     select f).FirstOrDefault();

            context.Movements.InsertOnSubmit(movement);
            context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Are you sure that an `Account` is found? It looks like `FirstOrDefault` creates a new default object because there is no match with `ChoosenAccount.Name`. Maybe ignoring case, or `Trim` will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896376.aspx) method for EntityRef such as `if (!order.CustomersReference.IsLoaded)
      order.CustomersReference.Load();`

Comment: the problem is on inserting data, not on retrieving. I edited the description hoping to be more clear, my fault.